# Run something when http observable has been subscribed to

Tags: http, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service that returns some data from an API:

```
// ...

getMetadata() {
    this.spinner.start();
    return this.http.get('/api/metadata').finally(() => this.spinner.stop());
}

// ....
```

I want to store the observable returned in a variable for use later on so in my component I go:

```
// ...
this.metadata$ = this.api.getMetadata();
// ...
```

And let's say I'm using this observable somewhere in my template using `| async`, but let's say this doesn't happen straight away.
What happens is, my spinner gets shown immediately anyway, even if the subscription wasn't placed at all.

So my question was, is there a way of defining an observable that'll call a function when first subscribed to, much like the `finally` operator, but for running something exactly when the observable is first (or every time) subscribed to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: " subscription wasn't placed at all".. you mean it goes to error or the request doesnt go?

Comment: No, I just mean no-one called `.subscribe` on it, yet or not at all

Comment: Because showing a spinner if I just "requested" an observable without ever subscribing to it, just doesn't make sense to me, even if not ever subscribing to an observable doesn't make much sense either

Comment: I would call the spinner before subscribing to the stored observable and then stop it in the complete of subscribe..Not sure if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: I can't do that if I'm using the `async` pipe and it's conditionally displayed using an `*ngIf`, meaning it will not necessarily subscribe, and definitely not onInit, you see my problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor(private _service:YourService) {}
 ngOnInit() {
   this._service.getMetadata().subscribe(
      (items)=>{
        this.metadata$=items,console.log(groups)
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: I want the data lazily, don't want to retrieve it if it's not being used, that's why I use the `async` pipe

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
getMetadata() {

    return Observable.of(this.spinner.start()).
          flatMap(()=> this.http.get('/api/metadata')).
          finally(() => this.spinner.stop());
}
```

Start the Observable with the spinner and then send the request with the flatMap and finally close the spinner.

Comment: The observable you create in the first line will be `of` the return value of `this.spinner.start()`, it won't call it when the observable gets subscribed but only return its return value (which is undefined in my case)

Comment: It will return the request value..  The first observable goes to flatmap..or use concatMap

Comment: No I mean, when the `getMetadata` function gets called, `this.spinner.start()` will get called immediately once more, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.